# Print a part of current path

Tags: bash, tr

We are having a small issue would appreciate any help.

We have the following path :

```
/root/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.sav
```

We also have :

```
 /root/dir1/dir2
```

We would like to do something like `/root/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.sav` - `/root/dir1/dir2` and get only `dir3/file.sav`.

We have tried working with `tr -d` but with no success.

Comment: What are you trying to do in general? Are you wanting to peel off the first N directories in the path, or take the last directory just before the name and get rid of however many are before that to the root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for an external tool.  Bash can solve this problem for you by itself.  Use `${variable#substring}` to print a variable with a substring deleted from the beginning.  Example:

```bsh
$ PATH1=/root/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.sav
$ PATH2=/root/dir1/dir2
$ echo ${PATH1#${PATH2}/}
dir3/file.sav
```

Comment: Working great ! :] *clap clap clap*

Answer (score 0):

Just offering other alternates...

**`bash`:**

```
echo ${PATH1/${PATH2}\//}
```

**`sed`:**

```
sed "s#$PATH2/##" <<< $PATH1
```

**`awk`:**

```
awk -v var="$PATH2" '{sub(var"/","",$0)}1' <<< "$PATH1"
```

**`replace`:**

```
replace "$PATH2/" "" <<< "$PATH1"
```